# How to validate controller request body where you don't have the source of the class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, validation, spring-webflux

I'm implementing a controller with a PATCH function.

```kotlin
@PatchMapping("/{id}", consumes = ["application/json-patch+json"])
suspend fun patch(
    @PathVariable
    id: UUIDv7,
    @Valid
    @RequestBody
    @ValidJsonPatch
    patch: JsonPatch,
): ResponseEntity<*> { ... }
```

`JsonPatch` is an interface in the `jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api` library, so I can't add any annotations to the class directly.

I've implemented a custom annotation and validator:

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [JsonPatchValidator::class])
annotation class ValidJsonPatch(
    val message: String = "",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = [],
)

class JsonPatchValidator : ConstraintValidator<ValidJsonPatch, JsonPatch> {
    override fun isValid(value: JsonPatch, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean { ... }
```

But my validator is never called. Standard Jakarta validation annotations are working as expected.

Can this be done? I'd much prefer the annotation instead of injecting a validator and doing it manually in every controller that implements PATCH.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using controller advice.

```kotlin
@ControllerAdvice
class WebDataBinderCustomizerAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    fun initBinder(binder: WebDataBinder) {
        binder.addValidators(JsonPatchValidator)
    }
}

object JsonPatchValidator : Validator {
    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>) = true

    override fun validate(target: Any, errors: Errors) {
        if (target !is JsonPatch) return
        // validation details
    }
}
```

Now my validator is called when the controller function argument is tagged with `@Valid` like this:

```kotlin
@PatchMapping("/{id}", consumes = ["application/json-patch+json"])
suspend fun patch(
    @PathVariable
    id: UUIDv7,
    @Valid
    @RequestBody
    patch: JsonPatch,
): ResponseEntity<*> { ... }
```

NB: The custom annotation is gone.